# MVVM: Binding values not being updated inside of a listview

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a list of objects being displayed in a List View and I want to update the value of one of the objects when another checkbox is checked. I then want the textbox displaying that value to be updated with this new value. 
Currently I have been able to get the object holding the other value and increment it but not display the new value.

```
<ListView Margin="0,5,5,5" Name="TruckModels" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="400" Width="1310" ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfTrucks}" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <!--New Version column-->
                <GridViewColumn Header="New Version" Width="105">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <TextBox AcceptsReturn="True" Height="Auto" Width="80" IsReadOnly="False" 
                                    x:Name="CurrentVersionTB" TextAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                                    Text="{Binding NewVersionVal}" 
                                    Foreground="#FFCD0000" 
                                    DataContextChanged="CurrentVersionTB_DataContextChanged"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                 <!--Auto-Increment Version? column-->
                <GridViewColumn Header="Auto-Increment&#10;   Version?" Width="105">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelectedAINV}" Checked="AutoIncrement_Checked" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
               </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

CS code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //List<Truckinfo> items = new List<Truckinfo>();
        ObservableCollection<Truckinfo> items = new ObservableCollection<Truckinfo>();

        xmlparsing(items);
        TruckModels.ItemsSource = items;
    }
    private void ScrollViewer_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        ScrollViewer scrollviewer = sender as ScrollViewer;
        if (e.Delta > 0)
        {
            scrollviewer.LineUp();
        }
        else
        {
            scrollviewer.LineDown();
        }
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    private void AutoIncrement_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Truckinfo item = (Truckinfo)(sender as CheckBox).DataContext;
        int i;
        int.TryParse(item.NewVersionVal, out i);
        i++;
        item.NewVersionVal = i.ToString();
        Debug.WriteLine(item.NewVersionVal);
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void CurrentVersionTB_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox t = sender as TextBox;
        t.BindingGroup.UpdateSources();

    }
}
```

I have tried to use INCP interface but it doesn't want to populate the table with the objects.

Comment: Please rpovide yout `Truckinfo` class. Maybe it needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: `Truckinfo` doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, is that what you're saying? *"it doesn't want to populate the table with the objects"* could mean virtually anything, since I have no way of guessing what "it", "the table", or "the objects" refer to. Can you describe what the actual problem was? You would be amazed at how many things in this world can be described with the word "it". Basically all of them. So it's hard to narrow down. I mean, there's an awful lot of things out there, just visible from my desk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ObservableCollection` only updates when the collection changes, not when an item changes.

You will have to have `TruckInfo` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for the individual item changes to update the view automatically.

Alternatively, you can remove the item from the Collection, and then re-insert the item. Then you will trigger the Collection change event, and the view will update to match the latest collection contents.

Comment: Thanks I Will implement INotifyPropertyChanged. I tried before but it was not populating my listview with my list of truck objects.

Comment: It's a hidden gotcha. Both the item and the collection need to be Observation/INotifyPropertyChanged for the view to be fully responsive.